# Page with wordpress return 500

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-500

I'm parsing a PHP file to another wordpress and the result say:

> Font from origin 'https://www.myweb.org' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://www.ayudaenaccion.org.pe' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

And the php that sould be the file have the next php code:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: WEB - NameFatherPage - NamePage 
*/
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

?>
```

I searched a solution, and in another places the people say that in wp-config.php i must change `define( 'force_SSL', true );` to `false`. But my site it's a multysite and i only have a wp-config.php.

How can solve the problem?

Comment: People say that you should change wp-config.php, and you have wp-config.php. What's the problem? You can't change this file?

Comment: the problem is that there are more wordpress using it, and the sub-wordpress look like that work without wp-config.

Comment: i must say that i didn't use wordpress previusly, and i trying understand many things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

[image]

the template (plantilla) was empty, then wordpress doesn't load the page